# Oracle(tm) Client & Newtworking Componets not Found

Tags: excel, oracle, vba

I am using Excel to connect to Oracle and am getting the error:

> The Oracle(tm) client and networking components were not found. These
>   components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the
>   Oracle Version 7.3 (or greater) client software installation. You will
>   be unable to use this driver until these components have been
>   installed.

Instant client is installed, the path and TNS_Admin variables are set, and the most confusing part is that everything worked before the computer was shut down yesterday. Does anyone know what could have changed when the computer was shut down?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the 64 bit client was installed instead of the 32 bit. It's still a mystery why the 64 bit worked until the computer was shut down.